# My code works when not indented and not in a def function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have a piece of code that runs correctly when I my code is not in a def function and not indented. Here is my code when it is indented.

```
import csv

my_file = open("marqueeTables.csv", "r")
search_data = input("Please enter the data you are looking for")
search_data = (search_data + " metre wide")
#print(search_data)
reader = csv.reader(my_file)
for row in my_file:
    if search_data in str(row):  # == "6 metre wide":
        stripedRow = row.strip()
        splitStrippedRow = stripedRow.split(",")[0]
        print(splitStrippedRow)
        #print(row)

It prints "6 metre wide" or "12 metre wide" depending on whether I type 6 or 12.
```

Here is similar code but in a def (only a few things have been changed):

```
def userInfo():

    while True:
        w = str(input("What size width marque would you like 6 or 12: "))

        if w == "6":
            myFile = open("userDetails.csv", "a+")
            myFile.write(str(w) + ", ")
            myFile.close()
            break
        elif w == "12":
            myFile = open("userDetails.csv", "a+")
            myFile.write(str(w) + ", ")
            myFile.close()
            break
        else:
            print("Pleas type 6 or 12")
        w = (w + "metre wide")

my_file = open("marqueeTables.csv", "r")
#search_data = input("Please enter the data you are looking for")
reader = csv.reader(my_file)
for row in my_file:
    if w in str(row):
        stripedRow = row.strip()
        splitStrippedRow = stripedRow.split(",")[0]
        print(splitStrippedRow)
userInfo()
```

When i run the code it prints "6 metre wide" and "Seating Capacity" and "12 metre wide" and "Seating Capacity" again (because it is in the table twice.)

Could someone tell my why my code is not working in python thanks that would be great. I am using python 3.5. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please read [mcve].

Comment: In your second code block you don't call the function `userInfo`...

Comment: Also in your second code block `elif w=="12":` should be unindented.

Comment: Yes it was unindented in my code but when i copied and pasted the code the indentation was wrong so i had to do it again and so ti went wrong @agold

Answer (score 1):

In the second code sample, you define `userInfo`, but you never call it, and so it is never run.

Comment: I have but it still doesn't run properly

Comment: @rodude123: I see no function call in the second snippet.  (Hint: It would look like `userInfo()`.)

Comment: Even after I have called the function it gives the wrong output i want is there another solution to this